# Multiple reads and writes on the pipe

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, pipe

I am not understand how pipe works very clearly. For the following program. The parent process write to the pipe twice and the child process read from the pipe twice, but on the second read, It seems like child only reads one character. The
output of the program is:

> [2297]:my bufin is {empty}, my bufout is {hello}
>
> [2298]:my bufin is {a}, my bufout is {hello}

Why the bufin for the children process is a instead of //aaa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define BUFSIZE 10

int main( void ) {
   char bufin[ BUFSIZE ] = "empty";
   char bufout[] = "hello";
   char b[] = "//aaa";
   int bytesin;
   pid_t childpid;
   int fd[ 2 ];
   if ( pipe( fd ) == -1 ) {
      perror( "Failed to create the pipe" );
      return 1;
   }
   bytesin = strlen( bufin );
   childpid = fork();
   if ( childpid == -1 ) {
      perror( "Failed to fork" );
      return 1; 
   }
   if ( childpid ) {      /* parent code */
      // Parent node write to the pipe.       
      write( fd[ 1 ], bufout, strlen( bufout ) + 1 );
      write( fd[ 1 ], b, strlen(b) + 1 ); // Just for trying
   }
   else {                 /* child code */
      bytesin = read( fd[ 0 ], bufin, BUFSIZE );
      bytesin = read( fd[ 0 ], bufin, BUFSIZE );  // Just for trying  
   }    
   fprintf(stderr, "[%ld]:my bufin is {%.*s}, my bufout is {%s}\n",
           (long)getpid(), bytesin, bufin, bufout);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This would make more sense if you printed the result of *both* reads. When you don't understand what's going on, deliberately hiding information from yourself is probably not a great idea. (Also, if you are writing NULs to one end of the pipe, you should expect to read them on the other end. That means that the buffer you read might have NULs in the middle, and not be NUL-terminated. That's a hint, too.)

Answer (score 2):

In first read you ask for BUFSIZE of bytes so read gets 'hello\0//aa' ( exactly 10 characters ). When you print this you see only 'hello' as there is NULL character after that. Only left character to read is one 'a' letter, which you see after second read. Also you forgot about closing unused end of pipe in parent and child. Please refer to very good guide on pipes: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/pipes.html